# user form issue while using modeless

Tags: combobox

i have a userform that has 4 comboboxs that are all populated using information on anther sheet (list Controls) this was all working fine until i made the userform modeless. each user will move between mutable excel files to get entrees that will populate the userform. when returning to the userform and entering the first letter they get subscript out of range error.
this is the code im using

Private Sub ACCOUNTNAME_change()

```
Dim i As Long
     
If Not IsArrow Then
    With Me.AccountName
        .List = Worksheets("list Controls").Range("A2", Worksheets("list Controls").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
        .ListRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(6, .ListCount)
        .DropDown
        If Len(.Text) Then
            For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If InStr(1, .List(i), .Text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .RemoveItem i
            Next
            .DropDown
        End If
    End With
End If
```

End Sub
Private Sub ACCOUNTNAME_keydown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
IsArrow = (KeyCode = vbKeyUp) Or (KeyCode = vbKeyDown)
If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then Me.AccountName.List = Worksheets("list Controls").Range("A2", Worksheets("list Controls").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
Me.AccountName.SetFocus
End Sub

error line is .List = Worksheets("list Controls").Range("A2", Worksheets("list Controls").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value

please help thanks

this is with Excel VBA

Comment: Please update your question and/or add a tag to help us know what app or language you are asking about. I'm guessing VBA in Excel?

Comment: yes this is with VBA IN Excel